# Where in Netbeans should I put my "mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" file?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, applet

I'm working in NetBeans, and have two projects. One is a JavaApplication project. This consists of an applet and some other classes. A couple of the classes make MySQL connections. When I run the Applet in this project, it works fine.

The second is a WebApplication project. It contains some html files, as well as a .jar of my JavaApplication project, so I can run the applet from the html files. When I run the WebApplication project, I get the ClassNotFoundException for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at the line in my code reading "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");"

I can only assume it's something wrong with where I'm adding the Driver, since when I don't run the web project and only run the applet, it works fine. Here is my Services and Projects tabs, please let me know if you detect something wrong:

[image: Services Space]

The database connection is alive and well, I can look into the tables from this view.

[image: Project Space]

Note that I placed the MySQL jar in the Libraries folder for both the JavaApplication and the WebApplication. I get the same result as when I only placed it in the Libraries folder for the JavaApplication.

Any ideas about what to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jar` files are library which are obviously to be placed in the `Library` section. So,the placement of your mysql-library is fine and OK. But, I doubt you are getting the error because of the unpresence of your ClassLoader files for applet_project! Secondly,the driver must be placed correctly which is fine in the Library folder.

```
public class ClassNotFoundException
```

is thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

The forName method in class Class.

The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .

The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

In your case, it seems that you haven't loaded your applet-based-project's jar file and that's what giving you ClassLoading related error!I suggest you to add the `applet_project.jar` of your applet_project. Also,I suggest you to delete the database configuration for `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample`,though it has nothing to do with your question. Also, the database `mysql...` must be connected by right clicking. Though this can be doen through code only,but alternatively you can try using both manually first and then through code!

Also,feel free to comment if you don't get or achieve what you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out when I leave work and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

As you have two separate projects so you have to put mysql jar to both projects'  path. As per snapshot your configuration is ok and It should work fine.